# Weird Memory Problem in Simply Linked-List Implementation C

Tags: c, memory, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am coding a Simply Linked-List that has a struct of elements composed by {name, price}, and in some of the function I'm implementing are presenting a weird behavior. These functions are:

1. `PopFront`(That remove the last element of the list)
2. `PopByIndex`(That given an entry index, it will remove the element on that position)

What's happening exactly? Well, these functions do remove the element they are supposed to remove, but they somehow change the value of the price of another element of the list .

Example:

Before use remove functions

```
Name:        A  Price: 1.00
Name:        B  Price: 2.00
Name:        C  Price: 3.00
Name:        D  Price: 4.00
    --------
     |Menu|
    --------
(1) Add Element in Front
(2) Add Element in Back
(3) Add Element in Position
(4) Remove Element from Front
(5) Remove Element from Back
(6) Remove Element by Position
(7) Print List
(8) Calculate Itens Sum
(0) Exit Program
```

After remove D element it puts 0 to the price of A

```
Name:        A  Price: 0.00
Name:        B  Price: 2.00
Name:        C  Price: 3.00
    --------
     |Menu|
    --------
(1) Add Element in Front
(2) Add Element in Back
(3) Add Element in Position
(4) Remove Element from Front
(5) Remove Element from Back
(6) Remove Element by Position
(7) Print List
(8) Calculate Itens Sum
(0) Exit Program
```

I used gdb to see what moment exactly, the element is modified and found that is when I call `free()` to free the memory of the address of the element removed

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
typedef struct List List;

struct Node {
    char name[100];
    float price;
    int code;
    struct Node *prox; 
};

struct List{
    struct Node *head;
    int size;
};

Node* InstantiateNode() {
    Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof new_node);
    new_node->prox = NULL;
    return new_node;
}

void InitNode(Node *node, char *name, float price) {
    strcpy(node->name, name);
    node->price = price;
}

void PrintNode(Node node){
    printf("Name: %8s  Price: %.2f\n", node.name, node.price);
}

int EmptyList(List list) {
    return list.size == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

List *InstantiateList(void) {
    List *new_list = malloc(sizeof new_list);
    new_list->head = NULL;
    new_list->size = 0;
    return new_list;
}

void InitList(List *list, Node *new_node) {
    new_node->prox = list->head;
    list->head = new_node;
    list->size++;
}

void PushFront(List *list, Node *new_node) {
    if (EmptyList(*list)) {
        InitList(list, new_node);
        return;
    }
    Node *tracker = list->head;
    while (tracker->prox != NULL)
        tracker = tracker->prox;
    tracker->prox = new_node;
    list->size++;
}

void PushBack(List *list, Node *new_node) {
        InitList(list, new_node);
}

Node *TrackListbyIndex(List lista, int index) {
    if (index > lista.size) {
        printf("Unreachable List index \n"); // Warning
        return NULL;
    }
    int cont = 0;
    Node *aux = lista.head;
    while (cont != index) {
        aux = aux->prox;
        cont++;
    }
    return aux;
}

void PushByIndex(List *list, Node *new_node, int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        PushBack(list, new_node);
        return;
    }
    Node *aux = TrackListbyIndex(*list, index - 1);
    Node *aux2 = aux->prox;
    if (aux) {
        new_node->prox = aux->prox;
        aux->prox = new_node;
        list->size++;
    }
}

void PopFront(List *list) {
    if (EmptyList(*list))
        return;
    Node* aux = list->head;
    Node* tracker, *tracker_next;
    tracker = list->head;
    if (tracker->prox != NULL) {
        tracker_next = tracker->prox;
        while (tracker_next->prox != NULL) {
            tracker = tracker_next;
            tracker_next = tracker_next->prox;
        }    
        tracker->prox = NULL;
        aux = tracker_next;
    }
    if (aux == list->head) {
        list->head = NULL;
    }
    free(aux);
    list->size--;
}

void PopBack(List* list){
    if(EmptyList(*list))
        return;
    Node* aux = list->head;
    list->head = list->head->prox;
    free(aux);
    list->size--;   
}
void PopByIndex (List *list, int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
        PopBack(list);
        return;
    }
    //if (index + 1 == list->size) {
    //    PopFront(list);
    //    return;
    //}
    Node *aux, *aux_next;
    aux = TrackListbyIndex(*list, index - 1);
    if (aux) {
        aux_next = aux->prox;
        aux->prox = aux_next->prox;
        free(aux_next);
        list->size--;
    }
}

void PrintList(List list) {
    Node *tracker = list.head;
    while (tracker != NULL) {
        PrintNode(*tracker);
        tracker = tracker->prox;
    }
}

void Menu(void);
void HandleMenu(int);

int main(void) {
    int option;
    for (;;) {
        Menu();
        printf("Type your choosen:");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        system("clear");
        HandleMenu(option);
    }
    return 0;
}

void Menu(void) {
    printf("\t--------\n");
    printf("\t |Menu|\n");
    printf("\t--------\n");
    printf("(1) Add Element in Front\n");
    printf("(2) Add Element in Back\n");
    printf("(3) Add Element in Position\n");
    printf("(4) Remove Element from Front\n");
    printf("(5) Remove Element from Back\n");
    printf("(6) Remove Element by Position\n");
    printf("(7) Print List\n");
    printf("(8) Calculate Itens Sum\n");
    printf("(0) Exit Program\n");
}

void HandleMenu(int option) {
    static List *market_list = NULL;
    Node* new_node = NULL;
    char node_name[100];
    float node_price;
    int index;
    if (market_list == NULL)
       market_list = InstantiateList();
    switch (option) {
      case 0:
        exit(1);
        break;
      case 1:
        new_node = InstantiateNode();
        printf("Type the product's name: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", node_name);
        printf("Type the product's price: ");
        scanf("%f", &node_price);
        InitNode(new_node, node_name, node_price);
        PushFront(market_list, new_node);
        printf("Item Added\n");
        break;
      case 2:
        new_node = InstantiateNode();
        printf("Type the product's name: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", node_name);
        printf("Type the product's price: ");
        scanf("%f", &node_price);
        InitNode(new_node, node_name, node_price);
        PushBack(market_list, new_node);
        printf("Item Added\n");
        break;
      case 3:
        new_node = InstantiateNode();
        printf("Type the product's name: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", node_name);
        printf("Type the product's price: ");
        scanf("%f", &node_price);
        InitNode(new_node, node_name, node_price);
        printf("Type Index: ");
        scanf("%d", &index);
        PushByIndex(market_list, new_node, index-1);
        printf("Item Added\n");
        break;
      case 4:
        PopFront(market_list);
        break;
      case 5:
        PopBack(market_list);
        break;
      case 6:
        printf("Type Index: ");
        scanf("%d", &index);
        PopByIndex(market_list, index-1);
        break;
      case 7:
        PrintList(*market_list);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of your output - add it as text in a code block to your question. Links to github are equally not great. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? As a code block in your question?

Comment: Please edit your question to supply a [mre] instead of a snippets of (incomplete) code.

Comment: I've edit my question an supplied a minamal reprodicible example, I guess (Sorry for the inconvenience, it's my first question here)

Comment: If you want to change the pointer passed in then it has to be **.  Posting your whole isn't what is meant with minimal, btw.

Comment: `Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof new_node);` allocates size of a pointer but you want `sizeof *new_node` to allocate size of a node.

Comment: Yes, I think that this allocation what causing the weird behavior in my code, I've edited it and it's working now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. `InstantiateNode()` allocates space for a `Node *` but you want space for the `Node`:

```
Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof *new_node);
```

2. `InstantiateList()` allocates space for a `List *` but you want space for the `List`:

```
List *new_list = malloc(sizeof *new_list);
```

After those two changes here is the output after the removal:

```
Name:        A  Price: 1.00
Name:        B  Price: 2.00
Name:        C  Price: 3.00
```